# arabic characters in oracle database

Tags: oracle, encoding, ora-01858

Dear all, I am trying to do the following.

I want to store Arabic characters in my database but the problem they are stored like that '??? ????'.  I have tried with these function:

```
msg_txt:=convert(msg_txt, 'AR8MSWIN1256', 'AR8ISO8859P6');
```

but I got this error:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

any suggestion please?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is your database and national character set?  If you're not sure

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameter
 WHERE name LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

What is the data type of the msg_txt variable?  CHAR/ VARCHAR2?  Or NCHAR/ NVARCHAR2?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the data type is `nvarchar` (unicode)

Comment: That depends on the database and national character set.  It is entirely possible that a VARCHAR2 in Oracle would use Unicode and entirely possible that a NVARCHAR2 would not.