# Oracle connection to retrieve or insert Arabic values from database

Tags: php, oracle, drupal

I have this code in drupal 6 to retrieve arabic values from Oracle databse:

```
           <?php
            session_start();
            $conn=oci_connect('localhost','pass','IP....');
            $stid=oci_parse($conn,"select arabic_name from arabic_names_table");
            oci_execute($stid);
            if($row-oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURNS_NULLS))
                {
                 $name_ar=$row['arabic_name'];
                 }
           ?>
```

When values are retrieved from the DB or inserted to the DB they appears like this ???

Please note:

- My Oracle database reads normal Arabic characters. From PL/SQL I can insert arabic values
- I have installed the mbstring
- I have the utf-8 encoding enabled.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the database character set?  What is the national character set?  What data type is `ARABIC_NAME` in `ARABIC_NAMES_TABLE`?

Comment: In addition to Justin's questions, have you set the NLS_LANG environment variable in the client environment, before connecting to Oracle?

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295866/arabic-characters-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the oracle database, when you try to fetch data, normally you will get the character encoding will be the encoding type of the client installed in the system (the machine that you installed the php). This encoding will be the charset of the windows registry for the oracle client.  (see `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1`), and the key is `NLS_LANG`. If you search the value of the above key, you will get something like `ARABIC_UNITED ARAB EMIRATES.AR8MSWIN1256`. Please note that the encoding type is `AR8MSWIN1256`. In the character map array this is mapped to `windows-1256` ( `windows-1256 => AR8MSWIN1256` ).

See this link [http://websvn.projects.ez.no/wsvn/ezoracle/?op=comp&compare[]=%2Fstable@385&compare[]=%2Fstable@386](http://websvn.projects.ez.no/wsvn/ezoracle/?op=comp&compare%5B%5D=/stable@385&compare%5B%5D=/stable@386).

That is, after you fetch the data from the database the char encoding will be `windows-1256`. Now if your web page is using `utf-8` charset, you need to convert the string to `utf-8`. For this you can use `iconv()`.

```
$win1256 = iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', $my_string); //$my_string -> windows-1256    
echo $win1256; // Results the utf-8 format .
```

If you are still facing problem you check the charset in the page, it must be `utf-8`.
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I think this will solve your problem.